# Confusion with changing variables in second order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, substitution, chain-rule

So in my physics assignment, we're given Schrodinger's equation:
$$\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+e\xi x\psi=E\psi$$
We're asked to substitute a function of the form $w(x)=Ax+B$ to arrive at an equation of the form
$$\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial w^2}-w\psi=0$$
So I have a fair idea of how to approach this, and I've made good progress, but I have couple points of confusion:

1. Where does the partial come from? Since the function is explicitly and implicitly of one variable, shouldn't we simply have full derivatives?
2. Am I using the chain rule correctly here:
   $$\frac{d\psi}{dw}=\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dw}$$
   $$\frac{d^2\psi}{dw^2}=\frac{d}{dw}\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dw}\right)=\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\frac{dx}{dw}+\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dw^2}$$

Comment: Note that: $\frac{d^2\psi}{dw^2} = \frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\left(\frac{dx}{dw}\right)^2 + \frac{d\psi}{dx} \frac{d^2x}{dw^2}$. You are missing a factor of $\frac{dx}{dw}$ in the first term.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Is there a deeper explanation of this? We haven't really covered this case in calculus, and Google is less than helpful...

Comment: Chain-rule again: $\color{red}{\frac{d}{dw}}\frac{d\psi}{dx} = \color{red}{\frac{dx}{dw} \frac{d}{dx}} \frac{d\psi}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dw}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$

Comment: cheers for that, I got a bit confused about how to apply the chain rule here

Comment: As for your first question: notation is often abused and $\partial \psi / \partial x$ is used interchangibly with $d\psi/dx$. You are correct that in this particular case where $\psi = \psi(x)$ the latter form should probably be used.

Comment: yup, I just said that since they're functions of single variables I can just change the full to a partial and it's still valid... I was just wondering if I was missing anything

Comment: btw if you want you can write up an answer to your own question. That way the question has an answer (which is always better than having it in comments) and it might be useful for other people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
1. Physics lecturers abuse notation, so here partials are used interchangeably with full derivatives.
2.
$$\frac{d}{dw}\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dw}\right)=\frac{d}{dw}\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dw}+\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{d}{dw}\frac{dx}{dw}=\frac{dx}{dw}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{dx}{dw}+\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dw^2}=\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\left(\frac{dx}{dw}\right)^2+\frac{d\psi}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dw^2}$$